# Using init as a Closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures, init

Recently I saw the following code line in a book (about CoreData)

```
return modelURLs(in: modelName).compactMap(NSManagedObjectModel.init)
```

I know what the code does but the question is: Why and how does it work? 
There should be a closure as the argument of the compactMap function but there's only a "NSManagedObjectModel.init" in **NORMAL** parenthesis. What's the secret about it? What is it doing there? I would understand it if there's a static/class property called init which returns a closure but I don't think there is.

Unfortunately the book doesn't say more about this line of code. I would like to have further readings from the apple docs but I can't find anything. When I make a google search about "init in closures" then I don't get helpful results.

So you guys are my last hope :)

By the way: the function modelURLs(in: modelName) returns an Array of URLs but that's not really important here.

Comment: this is just a syntax sugar, it is the same as `compactMap { NSManagedObjectModel.init($0) }`, no magic here

Comment: Yes, you can write compactMap({ NSManagedObjectModel.init(contenstOf: $0) }) which would work as well and that would be understandable, but what if there are two initializers? How does Swift or rather the compiler know which one to use?

Comment: I think you would get an error than if it is not clear which init method to use so then you would need to specify which one you want to use

Comment: No you won't. When you're going for the UIImage example then UIImage(contentOfFile:) is being used and not UIImage(named:). So you won't get an error, you just get an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

When using closures different syntax can be used as in the below example that converts an int array to a string array

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
```

The following calls to `compactMap` will all correctly convert the array and generate the same result

```
let out1 = array.compactMap({return String($0)})
let out2 = array.compactMap({String($0)})
let out3 = array.compactMap {String($0)}
let out4 = array.compactMap(String.init)
```

When there are two init methods that takes the same number and types of argument then you must add the full signature for the init method to use. Consider this simple example struct

```
struct TwoTimesInt: CustomStringConvertible {
    let value: Int
    let twiceTheValue: Int

    var description: String {
        return "\(value) - \(twiceTheValue)"
    }

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
        self.twiceTheValue = 2 * value
    }
}
```

With only 1 init method we can do

```
let out5 = array.compactMap(TwoTimesInt.init)
```

But if we add a second init method

```
    init(twiceTheValue: Int) {
        self.value = twiceTheValue / 2
        self.twiceTheValue = twiceTheValue
    }
```

Then we need to give the full signature of the init method to use

```
let out6 = array.compactMap( TwoTimesInt.init(value:) )
```

Another thing worth mentioning when it comes to which method is selected is to look at the full signature of the init method *including* if it returns an optional value or not. So for example if we change the signature of the second init method to return an optional value

```
    init?(twiceTheValue: Int) {
        self.value = twiceTheValue / 2
        self.twiceTheValue = twiceTheValue
    }
```

then `compactMap` will favour this init since it expects a closure that returns an optional value, so if we remove the argument name in the call

```
let out7 = array.compactMap(TwoTimesInt.init)
```

will use the second init while the `map` function on the other hand will use the first init method if called the same way.

```
let out8 = array.map(TwoTimesInt.init)
```

Comment: Thanks, a good answer, but why is it that I don't have to give the full signature in the case of UIImage.init? It also has more init Methods with one argument.

Comment: Not sure which ones you mean but I see that there are both ordinary an optional init methods with one argument and in that case it uses the optional one for compactMap

Comment: @AndreasUtzinger I added some more info to my answer

Comment: Thought the same, but in the UIImage class both init?(named: String) and init?(contentsOfFile: String) are optional inits, both have one argument and in both cases the argument is a string. And when you write just "UIImage.init" in a closure then always the latter will be used.

Comment: @AndreasUtzinger If you read the documentation for those two methods you realise  that they are very similar and although it is not explicitly mentioned it feels like one is a wrapper around the other.